# update multiple form using codeiginiter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to update data for multiple users using codeginiter, I used the bellow script but it only updates for one user.

```
<?php echo form_open(base_url() . 'get/save_payment', array('role' => 'form')); ?>
<?php foreach ($mature as $key => $value) { ?>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $value->id; ?>" readonly name="id[]">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $value->name; ?>" readonly name="name[]">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" value="0" readonly name="amount[]">
<?php } ?>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Confirm Request</button>
<?php echo form_close(); ?>

CONTROLLER

public function save_payment() {
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('id[]', 'id', 'required|trim');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('name[]', 'name', 'trim');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('amount[]', 'Amount', 'required|max_length[4]|trim|strip_tags');

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
        $this->session->set_flashdata('id', set_value('id'));
        $this->session->set_flashdata('name', set_value('name'));
        $this->session->set_flashdata('amount', set_value('amount'));
        $this->payment();
    } else {

        $id = set_value('id[]');
        $data['amount'] = set_value('amount[]');
        $data['name'] = set_value('id[]');

        $this->dashboard->update_ph($data,$id);
    }
}
```

Here is the MODEL :

```
public function update_ph($data,$id)
{
    $this->db->where('id', $id);
    $this->db->update('gw_ph', $data);
}
```

Kindly explain on how I can go through this code and get it working without error.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Codeigniter use 'name' attributte for get data from 'input' and you use same 'name' attributte for all of your readonly input